# Javascript not working in WP

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I am using this chart [js](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/master/Chart.js) with its [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) but is not showing inside my Wordpress post. I did not host the js file since I can only use it from github.

Code in my WP post:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/master/Chart.js">

var data = {
    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            data : [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
        },
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            data : [28,48,40,19,96,27,100]
        }
    ]
}

//Get the context of the canvas element we want to select
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data,options);

</script>
```

**Updated Code Still not working:**

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" src>// <![CDATA[


var data = {
    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            data : [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
        },
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            data : [28,48,40,19,96,27,100]
        }
    ]
}

Line.defaults = {

    //Boolean - If we show the scale above the chart data           
    scaleOverlay : false,

    //Boolean - If we want to override with a hard coded scale
    scaleOverride : false,

    //** Required if scaleOverride is true **
    //Number - The number of steps in a hard coded scale
    scaleSteps : null,
    //Number - The value jump in the hard coded scale
    scaleStepWidth : null,
    //Number - The scale starting value
    scaleStartValue : null,

    //String - Colour of the scale line 
    scaleLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,.1)",

    //Number - Pixel width of the scale line    
    scaleLineWidth : 1,

    //Boolean - Whether to show labels on the scale 
    scaleShowLabels : true,

    //Interpolated JS string - can access value
    scaleLabel : "<%=value%>",

    //String - Scale label font declaration for the scale label
    scaleFontFamily : "'Arial'",

    //Number - Scale label font size in pixels  
    scaleFontSize : 12,

    //String - Scale label font weight style    
    scaleFontStyle : "normal",

    //String - Scale label font colour  
    scaleFontColor : "#666",    

    ///Boolean - Whether grid lines are shown across the chart
    scaleShowGridLines : true,

    //String - Colour of the grid lines
    scaleGridLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",

    //Number - Width of the grid lines
    scaleGridLineWidth : 1, 

    //Boolean - Whether the line is curved between points
    bezierCurve : true,

    //Boolean - Whether to show a dot for each point
    pointDot : true,

    //Number - Radius of each point dot in pixels
    pointDotRadius : 3,

    //Number - Pixel width of point dot stroke
    pointDotStrokeWidth : 1,

    //Boolean - Whether to show a stroke for datasets
    datasetStroke : true,

    //Number - Pixel width of dataset stroke
    datasetStrokeWidth : 2,

    //Boolean - Whether to fill the dataset with a colour
    datasetFill : true,

    //Boolean - Whether to animate the chart
    animation : true,

    //Number - Number of animation steps
    animationSteps : 60,

    //String - Animation easing effect
    animationEasing : "easeOutQuart",

    //Function - Fires when the animation is complete
    onAnimationComplete : null

}

//Get the context of the canvas element we want to select
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, Line.defaults);

// ]]></script>
```

Comment: Your URL Seems Wrong. Please check it out . 
`<script src="https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/master/Chart.js">`

Comment: Should I use this instead: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nnnick/Chart.js/master/Chart.js?

Comment: This is the perfect link. Better you could copy the content and place it in your local then upload it to your server. And check it out for proof. It will surely work

Comment: yes, the one in comment is correct use it.(js in question is incorrect url)

Comment: Thanks for fixing the link. However it is not working still. I don't know what to post in `options`